# Existe algum problema em não colocar "/" (barra) em tags com auto fechamento?

Tags: html

Quando eu estava aprendendo a respeito do HTML, li que existem dois tipos de *tags*, as que são necessárias 'fechar', (`<tag></tag>`, ex: `<div></div>`) e as com auto fechamento (`<tag/>`, ex: `<img src="#"/>`), porém me deparei com um inconveniente (ou não), que é o seguinte, fechando ou não minhas tags de auto fechamento, elas funcionam da mesma maneira, por exemplo:

Isto

`<img src="#" />`

É o mesmo que isso (note que não fechei a *tag* com a barra)

`<img src="#">`

O mesmo pode ser reparado em *tags* `br`, `input`, etc.

Minha dúvida é, qual a diferença entre fechar ou não essas *tags*? Que riscos eu corro?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A ideia de fechar as tags sem filhos vem do XML, numa proposta de unificar as duas linguagens criando a XHTML. Entretanto, pelo que sei isso não foi pra frente - nem esse requisito foi adotado no HTML5.

Desse modo, fechar essas tags não é obrigatório, mas é opcional caso você deseje fazê-lo. Eu sempre faço, por "estética" mesmo, mas não é necessário.

(Cabe lembrar que, se a tag **não for** uma das listadas como "sem filhos", não fechar é sim um erro - ainda que os browsers "se virem" para interpretar o conteúdo pra você. Mas nesse caso, o fechamento deve-se dar por uma tag de fechamento distinta. Mais detalhes adiante)

Notas:

1. Aqui está [o trecho da especificação](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/syntax.html#syntax-start-tag) que fala sobre esse tipo de tag. [Essa pergunta no SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3558119/520779) também dá mais informações.
2. Também baseado nos recursos acima, é bom frisar que em HTML5 `<elemento />` é interpretado como simplesmente `<elemento>`, e não como `<elemento></elemento>` como seria feito no XML. Portanto, se você quer criar um tag sem filhos - quando essa tag *admite* filhos - não use essa forma simples.

   - Mais especificamente, a `/` é admitida nos [tipos de elemento](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#elements-0) vazio (*void elements*) e estrangeiro (*foreign elements* - elementos que fogem do HTML, como SVG ou MathML). Nos primeiros, ele se comporta como descrito, ignorando a `/`. Nos outros, ele se comporta como no XML, fechando o elemento. Usar a `/` num elemento que não é nem *void* nem *foreign* - como por exemplo um `div` - está incorreto segundo a especificação.

Comment: Apenas um complemento à resposta acima: de fato é opcional colocar a barra de fechamento numa self-closing tag (por exemplo, `<br />`) mas acho que fica interessante para diferenciar as self-closing tags das tags normais.

Answer (score 0):

Se você estiver utilizando o `XHTML` com Java por exemplo, Tags sem fechamento necessitam do `/>` no fim, assim como atributos alguns atributos que precisam receber como valor seu próprio nome. Já em `HTML` não existe essa necessidade, entretanto é uma boa pratica incluir sim o fechamento, ex: `<br />` `<hr />` ...

Comment: Alguém ainda usa XHTML, quando o HTML5 já suporta as tags `void` com `/>` e `>`? Creio que Java não tenha relação alguma, mesmo que esteja falando de algum framework estou quase certo que ele deve estar em uma versão mais atualizada que usa/suporta HTML5.