# Problema com evento hover no Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, css-hover, jquery-toggleclass

O código seguinte consiste em utilizar o evento *hover* na primeira imagem e trocar a classe da segunda. Porém após testes, o mesmo não funcionou no navegador Firefox, funcionando apenas nos navegadores Chrome, Safari e Opera.

Segue exemplo do código:

HTML

```
<img id="work1" src="/images/summer.jpg" alt="" width= /><a href="#um"></a>
<img id="work2" src="/images/winter.jpg" alt="" width= /><a href="#um"></a>
```

CSS

```
 #work1{
   cursor:pointer;
 }

 #work2{
   cursor:pointer;
 }

 #work2.tone{
  content:url(/images/click.svg);
 }
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$('#work1').hover(function(){
  $("#work2").toggleClass("tone");
});
```

Quais seriam as soluções para esse mal funcionamento?

Comment: Antes uma dúvida: para que usar javascript para fazer hover, se você pode fazer isso usando css?

Comment: Não consegui arranjar uma solução em que fizesse hover na imagem 1 (#work1) e alterasse a imagem 2 (#work2) no CSS. Estou aberto a sugestões. Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: @IvanFerrer, poderia ter usando a imagem como background de uma div ao inves de uma tag img

Comment: Olá @TobyMosque, há várias formas de fazer, a melhor com certeza seria usando um background, porém, estou apresentando uma solução simples, um outro exemplo de resolver seria fazendo isso: `.attr('style','background:url(/images/click.svg)')`... mas o importante é funcionar, certo.

Comment: @IvanFerrer, adicionei uma resposta com um exemplo usando background-image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Em relação ao bug:**

Pode ser algo da biblioteca Jquery em si, algo do navegador, ou algo no seu código que ocasionou o erro, são muitas as possibilidade e para encontrar a solução desse código você ira conseguir apenas debugando o mesmo.

---

**Em relação as soluções:**

SOLUÇÃO I:

Aconselho a fazer esse efeito utilizando CSS, além de ser a função dele fazer esse tipo de interação, você evita fazer duas manipulações diretamente no DOM com *Jquery*, economizando memória.

Nesse caso você utilizará um [seletor](http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/guia-completo-seletores-css3.php) CSS3 que atribui interação ao elemento imediatamente procedido a ele representado pelo sinal de soma (+).

Exemplo:

```css
/*Style default*/
img {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}


/* Seletor e exemplo de interação */
#work1:hover + a + #work2 {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<img id="work1" src="/images/summer.jpg" alt="Imagem I"><a href="#um"></a>
<img id="work2" src="/images/winter.jpg" alt="Imagem II"><a href="#um"></a>
```

Explicação:

Copiei seu HTML e com CSS atribui o evento de *hover* ao **#work1** depois passei o caminho até chegar ao **#work2**, adicionando o seletor **+** entre cada elemento.

SOLUÇÃO II:

Caso opte por fazer utilizando derivados de *javascript*, sugiro que utilize o seguinte código:

```js
document.querySelector('#work1').addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
  document.querySelector('#work2').classList.add('tone');
});
document.querySelector('#work1').addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
  document.querySelector('#work2').classList.remove('tone');
});
```

```css
img {
 border: 1px solid black;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
}
img.tone {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<img id="work1" src="/images/summer.jpg" alt="Imagem I"><a href="#um"></a>
<img id="work2" src="/images/winter.jpg" alt="Imagem II"><a href="#um"></a>
```

Explicação:

Seleciono os elementos utilizando o *querySelector*, onde o primeiro recebe o evento de *mouseover* e o segundo a *classList*, nesse exemplo ela serve como equivalente nativo do *toggleClass* porém os dois têm uma [pequena diferença](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29781833/classlist-toggleclass-true-vs-classlist-add).

---

**Observações:**

- Caso opte por fazer com CSS, tente utilizar o seletor para elementos diretamente seguidos, ou seja, retirando o elemento `<a>` entre eles para evitar autos níveis de [especificidade de seletores](http://tableless.com.br/afinal-como-usar-heranca-no-css/).
- Para o elemento `<img>` lembre-se de adicionar valor ao [atributo *alt*](http://tableless.com.br/o-poder-do-atributo-alt/) o mesmo é importante para SEO e acessibilidade e ao final você pode [retirar a barra (/)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9821/existe-algum-problema-em-n%C3%A3o-colocar-barra-em-tags-com-auto-fechamento) antes do fechamento da tag, se você estiver utilizando HTML5.
- Para o caso da solução em *javascript*, você pode alterar diretamente
  o valor do *src*, sem ter que utilizar a classe "tone", substituindo
  o *classList* por **.src="caminho da imagem"**. Exemplo:
  `document.querySelector('#work2').src="/images/click.svg";`

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Obrigado pelo feedback @costinha, qualquer duvida, pode perguntar!

Comment: Aconselharam usar a imagem como BG, aconselharam a usar CSS 3, etc... Mas teria que ajuda-lo com o que ele tinha. E se ele tiver que dar suporte pra IE8-??

Comment: @DanyloSantoro, como você é novo aqui, talvez não saiba que quando a resposta é marcada como correta é porque ajudou o usuário. O que foi pedido na pergunta, foi auxiliado, além disso eu não encontrei nada na pergunta que fale em relação a suporte ao IE8 e até onde sei, utilizar o que o usuário já tem não é uma obrigatoriedade o objetivo é propor soluções, porém se puder me provar o contrario agradeço, pois também gostaria de saber mais sobre. Agora, se você achou a resposta não satisfatória, sinta-se a vontade para elaborar uma nova.

Comment: Agradeço toda a disponibilidade e todas as palavras. Já agora as imagens que tenho de trocar com o hover, estão vários elementos à frente e algumas atrás do primeiro elemento. Existe alguma solução para isso através de outros selectores ou só temos o selector (+) ?

Comment: @costinha, você tentou a solução em Javascript? ela não depende do posicionamento dos elementos =]

Comment: Sim e funcionou. Estava só a confirmar se havia uma solução melhor em css para economizar memória. Obrigado mais uma vez!

Comment: Nesse caso não tem como, você vai precisar acessar os dois elementos via DOM mesmo! hehe

Answer (score 1):

Segue uma sugestão usando apenas CSS, neste caso use uma `div` ao invés de uma `img`, neste caso será importante informar o tamanho da imagem, assim como a url da mesma direto no CSS.

```css
.img {
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid gainsboro; 
  border-radius: 10px;

  transition-property: background-image;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}

.img {    
  background-image: url('http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/97199.png');

}

.img:hover {  
  background-image: url('http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/63511.png');
}
```

```html
<div class="img"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Experimente fazer assim:

```
$( '#work1' ).hover(
  function() {
    $( '#work2' ).attr("src", "/images/click.svg" );
  }, function() {
    $( '#work2' ).attr("src", "/images/winter.jpg" );
  }
);
```

Em jQuery, veja funcionando:

**http://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/mx0c65n4/**

Para fazer em css é muito simples, veja esse exemplo:

**http://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/da32dvnf/**

Comment: Obrigado funciona, mas ao retirar o rato a imagem não volta à original, algo que fazia anteriormente, excepto no firefox claro.

Comment: vc quer que volte, peraí.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda